# Issues with Modals React Native

Tags: reactjs, state, native

everyone. I'm new in this new tecnology and I'm having a little problem with modals.

I'm programming a modal that only shows when a condition is true, in the first click it's all ok, but in the second the modal won't show, then when I click again, the window appears again, and continue successively.

The code works as follow: I have 3 states, each represent a different text to show in the modal. Then, I have a modal, that recieves a message (to print) and the state to identifies what state i need to show. And finally, in the main, I have a condition who calls the modal and show it ONLY if the state is true.

I checked the states with console.log and the only issue i find is that in some cases, the state is set in true, when is false, but i don't know why!

Thanks for read!

Here i detach part of the code.

Declare of the states in the main

```
const [modalVisibleEnTermino, setModalVisibleEnTermino] = useState(false)

const [modalVisibleFueraTermino, setModalVisibleFueraTermino] = useState(false)

const [modalVisibleRefuerzoTermino, setModalVisibleRefuezoTermino] = useState(false)
```

Condtition in main to show the apropiate state of modal

```
const setModal = () => {
    vacunas ===2 && (days>6 && days<150) ? setModalVisibleEnTermino(true) : setModalVisibleFueraTermino(true)
    if(vacunas == 3)
        setModalVisibleRefuezoTermino(true)
}
```

Function to reset the states after showing modal (IDK if its ok)

```
 const restoreModals = () => {
    if (modalVisibleEnTermino) setModalVisibleEnTermino(false)
    if (modalVisibleFueraTermino) setModalVisibleFueraTermino(false)
    if (modalVisibleRefuerzoTermino) setModalVisibleRefuezoTermino(false)
}
```

After set the modal, I checked what state it's true, and I passed the values in this condition

```
{modalVisibleEnTermino && <MyModal
                    message={"Mensaje1"}
                    state={modalVisibleEnTermino}
                    />
                }

                {modalVisibleFueraTermino && <MyModal
                    message={"Mensaje2."}
                    state={modalVisibleFueraTermino}
                    />
                }

                {modalVisibleRefuerzoTermino && <MyModal
                    message={"Mensaje3."}
                    state={modalVisibleRefuerzoTermino}
                    />
                }
```

Modal

```
export const MyModal = (props) => {

const [visibleModal, setVisibleModal] = useState(props.state)
return (
  <Modal visible={visibleModal}
        transparent={true}
        animationType='slide'
        >
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.titulo_label}>¡IMPORTANTE!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.info_label}>{props.message}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button_aceptar} onPress={() => setVisibleModal(false)}>
          <Text style={styles.text_button}>Aceptar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  </Modal>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a restore property to your MyModal component

```
{modalVisibleEnTermino && <MyModal
                    message={"Mensaje1"}
                    state={modalVisibleEnTermino}
                    restore={restoreModals}
                    />
                }

                {modalVisibleFueraTermino && <MyModal
                    message={"Mensaje2."}
                    state={modalVisibleFueraTermino}
                    restore={restoreModals}
                    />
                }

                {modalVisibleRefuerzoTermino && <MyModal
                    message={"Mensaje3."}
                    state={modalVisibleRefuerzoTermino}
                    restore={restoreModals}
                    />
                }
```

In the MyModal Component remove the `useState` and pass the props.state to `visible` and use the `props.restore` on the `onPress` callback like so

```
export const MyModal = (props) => {

return (
  <Modal visible={props.state}
        transparent={true}
        animationType='slide'
        >
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.titulo_label}>¡IMPORTANTE!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.info_label}>{props.message}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button_aceptar} onPress={() => props.restore()}>
          <Text style={styles.text_button}>Aceptar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  </Modal>
);
```

In your original MyModal Component, by passing the props.state to useState, you are creating a new state within that component. Setting onPress to setVisibleModal(false) will not change the states of `modalVisibleEnTermino`, `modalVisibleFueraTermino`, and  `modalVisibleRefuerzoTermino`. By passing `restoreModals` as a prop to MyModal you can change the states in the Main component from inside MyModal.

One more thing, remove the if statements in your `restoreModals` function

```
 const restoreModals = () => {
    setModalVisibleEnTermino(false)
    setModalVisibleFueraTermino(false)
    setModalVisibleRefuezoTermino(false)
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it works! Thanks for reply!